# React (typescript version) app build by create-react-app breaks when I install material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I first used the command `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` to make a react application, which worked fine and there was no error in the console. then I executed `npm install @material-ui/core` to install material UI and after installing material-UI my react application starts showing the following error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'. 'C:/Users/91727/OneDrive/Desktop/test/node_modules/react/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.\n  If the 'react' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react`

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react/jsx-runtime'. 'C:/Users/91727/OneDrive/Desktop/test/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.\n  If the 'react' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react`
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in conversation about [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/23306), try to install `@material-ui/core` with `--legacy-peer-deps` option:

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps @material-ui/core
```